# Which dance step is done by the man at 0:04 - 0:10 & it’s name

Tags: dancing

In this video , the man is Hrithik Roshan & lady is Lauren gottlieb. I want to which dance step is done by Hrithik Roshan at 0:04 - 0:10 ? What is its name because i want to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body roll. Takes a while to learn.